For each integer $k,$ does there exist a $k-$tuple of primes, $(p_n)_{n=1}^{k},$ s.t. for each $n,\ p_{n+1}=2p_n- 1$ or $p_{n+1} =2p_n+1?$

For each $k\in\mathbb{N},$ does there exist a $k-$tuple of primes,
$(p_n)_{n=1}^{k},\ $ such that for each $n,$ the following is
satisfied: $p_{n+1} = 2p_n- 1\ $ or  $p_{n+1} = 2p_n + 1?$

If yes then further question: does there exist an infinitely long tuple of such primes (i.e. an infinite sequence)?
I suppose that this might be related to Collatz conjecture in some way, or might simply be an open problem.
Update: I have noticed that I can't find any tuples of length $>2$ for  quite a while up until I reach $p_1 = 331,$ where I get $(331,661,1321).$ There must be some modular arithmetic reason for what is going on?

Have you tried some ?

@EDX yes but I don't see any obvious patterns yet, although I have noticed that I can't find many long tuples if $p_1<1000$. What is the reason for this?

It is still an open problem whether there are infinitely many primes on the form $2p+1$ (Sophie Germain primes) or $2p-1$

@cansomeonehelpmeout That's true - I forgot about that! But maybe my conjecture can still be disproven with modular arithmetic?

The following is highly related. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture

If you think about the final digits of odd primes, you will realize that to produce long tuples, in the $2p-1$ case, the only possible final digit is $1$, and in the $2p+1$ case, the only possible final digit is $9$. Other final digits quickly yield a result with a final digit of $5$, which cannot be prime.


There is no relation to Collatz whatsoever.  2. The question can be reduced to whether there is an arbitary long sequence of such primes since then we can easily establish smaller collections by simply omitting the last (or the first primes). 3. $p_1=85864769$ gives $9$ primes , the best I found so far.


$$p_1=26\ 089\ 808\ 579$$ gives $10$ primes.

An infinitely long sequence does not exist:
We may assume $p_1 > 3$, and then by looking mod $3$, given $p_k$ there is only one possibility for $p_{k + 1} = 2 p_k \pm 1$ because one of the possibilities makes $p_{k + 1}$ divisible by $3$. In fact, the same sign must be used in each step so that there is a simple closed form, namely
$$p_{n} = 2^{n - 1} p_1 + 2^{n - 1} - 1$$
or
$$p_{n} = 2^{n - 1} p_1 - 2^{n - 1} + 1 \,.$$
This sequence is periodic modulo any odd number (because powers of $2$ are periodic modulo any odd number). In particular it is periodic modulo $p_1$, but also mod $p_2$ etc.
